# SQL Prepared Statement not Running?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I had the following .php file running asynchronously through AJAX from my main page that was supposed to submit comments:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "dxbase.php";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);



    $comment = "practice";
    $prid = 2;

    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

    $usera = $_SESSION['user'];


    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reviews (prid, content, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $prid, $comment, $usera);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Review submitted!";
    $stmt->close();




    } else {
        echo "Oops! You need to be signed in to review products!";



    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

When I ran it, it echoed back that it had submitted a comment but when I checked my database it wasn't there: [DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijm9i.png)

Why isn't it inserting?!

Comment: Try echoing $conn->error or $stmt->error and see what it says.

Comment: You should check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) along each step of the way.

Comment: The first `s` should be an `i` but that shouldn't affect it i wouldn't think. In the `"sss"` because it is an integer. Does `start` have a default value?

Comment: You don't check the results of any of your prepare, bind, or execute statements. Also it looks like `prid` is an integer not a string. That wouldn't stop things from working but best to fix it.

Comment: @user3783243 yeah it won't affect entry, it's semantics if it's a string based int etc

Comment: You should look into try catches for these stmt's